# CloudKit sync works when testing on devices in Xcode but not in production in the App Store

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I have a `SwiftUI` app that uses `CloudKit` and `Core data` to sync data between devices. Everything works fine when testing on devices in Xcode but not in production in the App Store.

1. Can someone explain the typical process when deploying an app that uses `CoreData + CloudKit`?
2. Is there anything that needs to be done in code or in the `CloudKit Console` before the app is uploaded to the `App Store`?

Again, my issue is that data doesn't sync when trying to sync data between multiple devices in production but works fine when testing in Xcode.

Thanks

Comment: You have to make sure you promote the schema to production https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/creating_a_core_data_model_for_cloudkit

Comment: I found this article a long time ago it is very informative https://www.grantgrueninger.com/2020/01/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-in-production/

Comment: Thank you for the links, they helped me a lot. The short answer to my question is that the Core Data scheme needs to be deployed to production.  Here is what I did that worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763283/how-to-update-the-cloudkit-schema-after-the-app-has-been-released-to-the-appstor